# Comparing integer and binary in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Can we compare integer and binary values in the if statement i.e
I have a comparing statement as

```
 if(o_remainder=remainder and o_quotient=quotient)
```

where `o_remainder` and `o_quotient` are of type `std_logic_vector`, and `remainder` and `quotient` are of type `integer`.

Comment: What is type `std_logic_vector`? Should they not be `logic`, `reg` or `wire` compared against `integer`. Did this not work when you tried it?

Comment: o_remainder is a reg of type std_logic_vector. and it worked only for few values. So i asked to be sure whether the comparision is valid or not.

Comment: Should this be tagged as VHDL rather than Verilog?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple test comparing regs to integers:

```
module test;

reg        [9:0]   val;
reg signed [9:0]   sval;


initial begin
  #1ns;

  val = 10'd1;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == 1);
  val = 10'd2;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == 2);
  val = 10'd3;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == 3);

  //Signed
  val = -10'd1;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == -1);
  val = -10'd2;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == -2);
  val = -10'd3;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", val == -3);

  // Using Signed register
  sval = -10'd1;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", sval == -1);
  sval = -10'd2;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", sval == -2);
  sval = -10'd3;
  #1 $display("is it equal %b", sval == -3);
end
endmodule
```

Gives me:

```
is it equal 1
is it equal 1
is it equal 1
is it equal 0
is it equal 0
is it equal 0
is it equal 1
is it equal 1
is it equal 1
```

For me the positive numbers work fine but fails with negative values. You have to declare the reg as signed. For the comparison to work. With that in mind you should be able to compare reg to integer.

Answer (score 1):

From your mention of std_logic_vector, I assume you are actually working in VHDL, not Verilog.

If your vectors represent numbers, use the `unsigned` or `signed` types from ieee.numeric_std, instead of vectors.  Then you can compare directly with integers.

If you insist on using std_logic vector, then convert it before:

```
 if unsigned(some_vector) < some_integer then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare. 
The difference between integer and reg is that `reg` by default is an `unsigned` type single bit value; whereas `integer` is `signed` type 32 bit value.
Make sure that `o_reminder` and `reminder` are of same type i.e, both are either `signed` or `unsigned`.
same case with the `o_quotient` and `quotient`.

I don't see any issue if you have declared as below.

```
integer o_reminder, o_quotient;
reg signed [31:0] reminder,quotient;
```

or

```
integer unsigned o_reminder, o_quotient;
reg [31:0] reminder,quotient;
```

Comment: Setting the width to 32 bits is not required.